# Angular 4 page reload or redirect throws "loadChunkError":true

Tags: angular6, webpack-2

I'm  using angular 6 MVC application with webpack build. It throws an **"loadChunkError":true"** randomly on page load or redirect,
After the error occurred, angular routing not works and throws an console error continuously.

[**Note:** Once i cleared the browser cache and then routing works fine]

**Webpack file**

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
```

`const path = require("path")`;

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var SourceMapDevToolPlugin = require('webpack/lib/SourceMapDevToolPlugin');
let SharedCache = {};
const entryPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");
const viewPath = path.resolve(
    __dirname,
    "../Views/Home"
);

const { BaseHrefWebpackPlugin } = require('base-href-webpack-plugin');
const ROOT = path.resolve(__dirname, '');
```

const app = `${entryPath}`;
module.exports = envOptions => {
  envOptions = envOptions || {};

```
const config = {
    entry: {
        polyfills: `${entryPath}\\polyfills.ts`,
        vendors: `${entryPath}\\vendor.ts`,
        app: `${entryPath}\\main.ts`
    },
    output: {
        path: viewPath,
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: "../../angularBundle/[name].js",
        chunkFilename: '../../angularBundle/[name].js',
        sourceMapFilename: "../../angularBundle/[name].js.map",
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js", ".html"],
        alias: {
            jquery: "jquery/src/jquery"
        }
    },  
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.ts$/,
      loaders: ["awesome-typescript-loader?configFileName=./src/tsconfig.json", "angular2-template-loader"]
      },
      {
          test: /\.(ts|js)$/,
          loaders: [
              'angular-router-loader'
          ]
      },
    {
      test: /\.html$/,
      loader: "raw-loader"
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loader: "raw-loader"
      }
      ,
      {
          test: /\.(png|jpg|eot|cur|svg|gif|ttf|woff|otf)$/,
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
              outputPath: 'fonts/'
          }
      } 
  ]
    },
    devtool: 'eval',
    plugins: [
  new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: viewPath + "/loader.cshtml",
        filename: viewPath + "/Index.cshtml",
        inject: false
        })
    ],
  optimization: {
      splitChunks: { chunks: 'all' },
    },
 };

if (envOptions.MODE === "prod") {
    config.plugins.push(
        new UglifyJsPlugin()
    );
  }

 return config;
};
```

**Error**

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Object: {"loadChunkError":true,"details":{"type":"missing","request"}

Please suggest a solution or steps to fix the issue.

Thanks,
Vivek

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: No I didn't found a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Root cause:** In my case,load chunk error exist which  due to old cached js chunks. 
**Fix:** Fixed the issue by generated the unique js with the help of hash

[hash] is a "unique hash generated for every build"

**Existing**
          `output: {
        path: viewPath,
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: "../../angularBundle/[name].js",
        chunkFilename: '../../angularBundle/[name].js',
        sourceMapFilename: "../../angularBundle/[name].js.map",
    }`

**Updated[Issue Fixed**]
`output: {
        path: viewPath,
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: "../../angularBundle/[name].[hash].js",
        chunkFilename: '../../angularBundle/[name].[hash].js',
        sourceMapFilename: "../../angularBundle/[name].[hash].js.map",
    }`

Answer (score 0):

- Step 1: Load your component directly by using `component` instead of `loadChildren` then you can see the actual error
- Step 2: Fix the error.
- Step 3: Load component lazily as you did before.